# Is there an abbreviation of “can not”?

Tags: word-usage

I’ve been using carnt but I don’t think it’s proper English, thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: **Cannot** -> ***Can't***. *No /r/ sound.* (Kaant)

Comment: Are you asking about "can not" rather than "cannot"?  "You have a choice: you can do it or you can not do it."

Answer (score 2):

Not *abbreviation*. It's called **contraction**.

**Contraction:** A contraction is a word made by shortening and combining two words.

**Examples:**

Cannot -> can't

Do not -> don't

Does not -> doesn't

Will not -> won't

Would not -> wouldn't etc.

✥━━━━✥━━━━✥

**Writing contractions:**
All contractions include a punctuation mark called *apostrophe* (**'**).

The apostrophe replaces any letters that are present in the original words but absent in the contraction.

The contraction, for example, **wouldn't** means **would not**. As you can see, the **O** in **not** is not present in **couldn't**. The apostrophe goes in its place, right between the **n** and **t**.

✥━━━━✥━━━━✥

Cannot -> can't

It's [pronunciation](http://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/pronunciation/english/cant) is different in AmE and BrE.

**BrE:** /kɑːnt/ (like *kaant*)

**AmE:** /kænt/ (same as *can* but add *t*)

✥━━━━✥━━━━✥

Here's a long explanation about contractions: 
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/contractions

**NOTE:** *Avoid contractions in formal writing, such as business letters, essays, technical papers, research papers and exams.*

### ☆━━✥✥✥━━☆☆━━✥✥✥━━☆☆━━✥✥✥━━☆